# I need to write 100 integers created randomly into a file using Java I/O

Tags: java

I need to write 100 integers created randomly into a file using Java I/O
this is my code so far:

```
package lab;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random num = new Random();

        try {
            File file = new File("E:\\Test.txt");
            if(file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
        }

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new File("E:\\Test.txt"));
        for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++){
             output.print(num.nextInt(100)+" "+num.nextInt(100) + " " +
            num.nextInt(100) + " " + num.nextInt(100) + " " + num.nextInt(100) + " "
            + num.nextInt(100) + " " + num.nextInt(100) + " " + num.nextInt(100) + " "
            + num.nextInt(100) + " " + num.nextInt(100));
            output.println();
        }
        out.close();

        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
        while(input.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(input.nextLine());
        }
        input.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("File Already Exists!");
        }
    }
}
```

I need to simplify the "for-loop", and be able to read back the file to display it.
Can anyone help?

Comment: I need to eliminate all the "num.nextInt(100)+"" with something else.

Comment: As I told you in your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30061912/how-do-i-create-a-file-with-100-random-numbers-using-the-mod-operator-in-java) which is almost an exact duplicate of this, you need to **be more specific**. `something else` tells us nothing about what you want to replace it with. Help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all do not concatenate Strings in for loops (new objects are created), use StringBuilder.

Once you build your string with random numbers save it like this:
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-to-file-in-java-bufferedwriter-example/

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
Random rng = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    str.append(rng.nextInt(100) + " ");

System.out.println(str.toString());
```

Replace `System.out.println(str.toString());` with your filestream writing.

Answer (score 0):

```
 File file = new File("File_name.txt");
 StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
 try (PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(file);) {
      for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
          int num = ((int)(Math.random() * 500) + 1);    
          output.print(num);
          output.print(" ");
          str.append(num + " ");
     }
}
System.out.println(str.toString());
```